# MethodNotAllowedHttpException for Post Method .Get and Head Supported

Tags: php, laravel, routes, methodnotfound

I defined my route in web.php as Post method. and csrf token is also added in form . Route:list command is working perfect and showing that post route. but when I submit form it shows The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

@csrf added to form tag.
php artisan route:list working properly showing that defined post route.

```
   <form method="POST" method="plantouser">
              @csrf
              <h1>Select Plan</h1>
              <div>
                <select name="plans" class="form-control">
                  @foreach($plan as $plan)
                  <option value="{{$plan->planamount}}">{{$plan->planname}} of {{ $plan->planamount}}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="separator">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

`Route::post('/plantouser','PlanController@planToUser');`

```
public function planToUser(Request $request){

    $payment=Planpaymentdetail::create([
            'paymenttype'=>'online',
            'pyamount'=>$price,
            'pycoinamount'=>$dec['result']['amount'],
            'pytxnhash'=>$dec['result']['txn_id'],
            'pyinitiatetime'=>now(),
        ]);
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Plan selected successfully');
}
```

[this image showing data which is post by form to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osv4y.png)

Expected Result is to redirect to url with message
but getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: Update the question with the full form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you post to should be set with the `action` attribute of your form tag, not the `method` attribute:

```
<form method="POST" action="/plantouser">
```

Comment: thanks for solving problem. a small thing was cause for problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('plantouser') }}">
```